# ggplot2 crashes Rstudio when the data has Chinese characters

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

When I plot data that has Chinese characters with ggplot in Rstudio, **Rstudio always crashes**. But when I remove all Chinese characters value, it works fine.
And it works also fine with Chinese value in R GUI.

It crashes like this:

[image]

My work path like this :

[image]

sessionInfo()
[image]

Rstudio version
[image]

**my plot code**

```
df <- data.frame(variable = 1:5, value = rnorm(5), group = c("优", "优", "优", "劣", "劣"))
ggplot(df,aes(variable,value))+ geom_bar(aes(fill=group),
       stat = "identity",position="dodge",width=0.8)
```

the group has Chinese charactar

**log file:**

> 19 Jun 2018 01:46:44 [rsession-MyUserName] ERROR system error 22
>   (设备不识别此命令。); OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error
>   rstudio::session::source_database::get(const string&, bool,
>   rstudio_boost::shared_ptr) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\session\SessionSourceDatabase.cpp:621;
>   LOGGED FROM: void
>   rstudio::session::modules::explorer::{anonymous}::removeOrphanedCacheItems()
>   C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\session\modules\SessionObjectExplorer.cpp:83
>
> 19 Jun 2018 01:46:44 [rsession-MyUserName] ERROR system error 22
>   (设备不识别此命令。); OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error
>   rstudio::session::source_database::get(const string&, bool,
>   rstudio_boost::shared_ptr) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\session\SessionSourceDatabase.cpp:621;
>   LOGGED FROM: rstudio::core::Error
>   rstudio::session::source_database::list(std::vector
>
> > *) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\session\SessionSourceDatabase.cpp:760

---

Okay, for a few months later, I finally get the answer of my question.

I have checked my data and code, but they run well in other PCs, which have the same brand and the same hardware condition. But there is still crash.
I checked my software part, the different versions of R, Rstudio and OS(win 10) are be tested in turn. Crash is still there.

But when I reinstall the OS of my PC at first, I find there is no crash when I did not install any software except R and Rstudio. Then it means some software interferes the work of Rstudio. Finally I caught the culprit, 
[Mactype](https://www.mactype.net), that is a replacement for the Windows default font rasterizer based on gdi++ .

So my question is changed to be: **how a rasterizer could interferes the Rstudio plot work?**

Comment: this would be a better question if you posted some sample code to go with your error.

Comment: @Gregor it’s just simply crush without any error code, and show r session stopped

Comment: You try to make a plot, then there is crash, right? Share sample code for the plot that causes the crash.

Comment: my plot code as my edition above

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with this: `df <- data.frame(variable = 1:5, value = rnorm(5), group = c("優", "優", "優", "劣", "劣")); ggplot(df,aes(variable,value))+ geom_bar(aes(fill=group), stat = "identity",position="dodge",width=0.8)`. It works just fine.

Comment: Does your user name or working path have Chinese characters?

Comment: @ytu no character in computer name and working path. I think it might be my computer problem, I use your example data, it still crashes.